# Dictionary/List speed for database update

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I've got my model updating the database according to some information that comes in in the form of a Dictionary. The way I currently do it is below:

```
SortedItems = db.SortedItems.ToList();
foreach (SortedItem si in SortedItems)
{
    string key = si.PK1 + si.PK2 + si.PK3 + si.PK4;
    if (updates.ContainsKey(key) && updatas[key] != si.SortRank)
    {
        si.SortRank = updates[key];
        db.SortedItems.ApplyCurrentValues(si);
    }
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

Would it be faster to iterate through the dictionary, and do a db lookup for each item? The dictionary only contains the item that have changed, and can be anywhere from 2 items to the entire set. My idea for the alternate method would be:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, int?> kvp in updates)
{
    SortedItem si = db.SortedItems.Single(s => (s.PK1 + s.PK2 + s.PK3 + s.PK4).Equals(kvp.Key));
    si.SortRank = kvp.Value;
    db.SortedItems.ApplyCurrentValues(si);
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

**EDIT**: Assume the number of updates is usually about 5-20% of the db entires

Comment: The main thing to remember is that more than likely, your database calls will be slower than a dictionary lookup.  So you want to try to minimize database interactions if possible (as a general rule of thumb).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look:

**Method 1:**

- You'd iterate through all 1000 items in the database
- You'd still visit every item in the Dictionary and have 950 misses against the dictionary
- You'd still have 50 update calls to the database.

**Method 2:**

- You'd iterate every item in the dictionary with no misses in the dictionary
- You'd have 50 individual lookup calls to the database.
- You'd have 50 update calls to the database.

This really depends on how big the dataset is and what % on average get modified.

You could also do something like this:

**Method 3:**

- Build a set of all the keys from the dictionary
- Query the database once for all items matching those keys
- Iterate over the results and update each item

Personally, I would try to determine your typical case scenario and profile each solution to see which is best.  I really think the 2nd solution, though, will result in a ton of database and network hits if you have a large set and a large number of updates, since for each update it would have to hit the database twice (once to get the item, once to update the item).

So yes, this is a very long winded way of saying, "it depends..."

When in doubt, I'd code both and time them based on reproductions of production scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @James' answer, you would get fastest results using a stored proc (or a regular SQL command).

The problem with LINQ-to-Entities (and other LINQ providers, if they haven't updated recently) is that they don't know how to produce SQL updates with `where` clauses:

```
update SortedItems set SortRank = @NewRank where PK1 = @PK1 and (etc.)
```

A stored procedure would do this at the server side, and you would only need a single db call.